# Creating a inla.graph object with correct index labels from sf linestring object

Tags: r, igraph, r-sf, r-inla, sfnetwork

I have a shapefile containing `linestrings` that describes connection between cities in Brazil. I would like to convert these connections into a neighbourhood object with the cities' code set as the row name, making it compatible with my data frame:

```
> head(regic_link)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 6 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -45.7931 ymin: -21.1472 xmax: -41.3903 ymax: -15.9032
proj4string:   +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
     id origin_code            nome_ori dest_code        nome_dest   dist_km                       geometry
1 14016     3123304      Dores do Turvo   3165701  Senador Firmino 11.732462 LINESTRING (-43.1884 -20.97...
2 14117     3124708   Estrela do Indaiá   3166600 Serra da Saudade  9.080594 LINESTRING (-45.7878 -19.52...
3 15205     3138658              Lontra   3135357         Japonvar 11.104687 LINESTRING (-44.3029 -15.90...
4 17147     3163300  São José do Divino   3144904      Nova Módica 13.066889 LINESTRING (-41.3903 -18.48...
5 17151     3163409 São José do Goiabal   3121803         Dionísio 12.078370 LINESTRING (-42.7077 -19.92...
6 12463     3102100       Alto Rio Doce   3121506 Desterro do Melo 17.982702 LINESTRING (-43.412 -21.025...
```

So the row name would be set as `origin_code` and the neighbour would be set to `dest_code` in the list and vice versa (eventually this would be changed to an index I create but this makes things easier to check). Essentially, I need the `linestring` equivalent for the following code used for polygons:

```
nb.orig <- poly2nb(as_Spatial(shp), row.names = shp$index)
names(nb.orig) <- attr(nb.orig, "region.id")

nb2INLA("output/nb_orig.graph",  nb.orig)
```

(`shp` is a shapefile consisting of polygons, and the `index` variable is present in both the shapefile and the data frame).

So far, I have used the `sfnetworks` and `igraph` packages to create a neighbourhood object but have not been able to attach index values to the row names:

```
regic_net <- as_sfnetwork(regic_link, directed = F) 

net_adj <- as_adjacency_matrix(regic_net, names = T)
nb_net <- mat2listw(net_adj)$neighbours
```

The function `as_sfnetwork` assigns a number to each of the nodes in the network by default (in the edge data, these are variables 'from' and 'to' and cannot be changed using mutate):

```
> regic_net
# A sfnetwork with 827 nodes and 3786 edges
#
# CRS:  NA 
#
# An undirected simple graph with 1 component with spatially explicit edges
#
# Edge Data:     3,786 x 7 (active)
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -50.6938 ymin: -22.855 xmax: -39.9496 ymax: -14.2696
   from    to origin_code nome_ori           dest_code nome_dest                                                                                    geometry
  <int> <int>       <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                                                                                <LINESTRING [°]>
1     1     2     3123304 Dores do Turvo       3165701 Senador Firmino    (-43.1884 -20.975, -43.18106 -20.97017, -43.17373 -20.96534, -43.16639 -20.9605, …
2     3     4     3163409 São José do Goiab…   3121803 Dionísio           (-42.7077 -19.9255, -42.71344 -19.91851, -42.71917 -19.91152, -42.72491 -19.90453…
3     5     6     3167707 Sobrália             3162609 São João do Orien… (-42.0972 -19.2363, -42.1016 -19.2437, -42.106 -19.2511, -42.11039 -19.2585, -42.…
4     5     7     3167707 Sobrália             3168408 Tarumirim          (-42.0972 -19.2363, -42.08899 -19.24038, -42.08079 -19.24447, -42.07258 -19.24855…
5     8     9     3115474 Catuti               3141009 Mato Verde         (-42.9607 -15.3612, -42.95243 -15.36428, -42.94415 -15.36735, -42.93588 -15.37043…
6    10    11     3130606 Inconfidentes        3108305 Borda da Mata      (-46.328 -22.3174, -46.31896 -22.31505, -46.30993 -22.3127, -46.30089 -22.31034, …
# … with 3,780 more rows
#
# Node Data:     827 x 1
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -50.6938 ymin: -22.855 xmax: -39.9496 ymax: -14.2696
             geometry
          <POINT [°]>
1  (-43.1884 -20.975)
2  (-43.1004 -20.917)
3 (-42.7077 -19.9255)
# … with 824 more rows
```

These values are then used as row names in the next step within the `nb` object created using `as_adjacency_matrix` and `mat2listw`. Does anyone know how to attach my own index or even extract the index that has been created so I can make it consistent between this and the data frame? I have tried to create a conversion table taking the `from`/`origin_code` and `to`/`dest_code` but these do not match, the `from` value is the lowest of the two indices and so is not always the origin in my data.

Also to make it more difficult, there are 57 more nodes than expected and I cannot find why this has happened. I have checked the duplicates, they have the same coordinates and code/name in the data but are being treated separately with a different index number.

In summary,  I'd like to convert a linestring object into a neighbourhood object that can be used in an INLA model where the cities connected by lines are considered neighbours.  I need to attach an index to these cities so the neighbourhood object sets the index as the row name and it can be combined with data in a model. Hope that makes sense, please let me know if not!

Comment: Hi Sophie! Can you share the shapefile?

Comment: Hi, I have added them to the following Dropbox folder https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7bgas78scsof95u/AAClDsGb-18p7m9otRzTK9Nda?dl=0 (I am not sure if this is the best way to share things on here but couldn't see anywhere to attach files!)

Comment: Hi. One more question (maybe related to the fact that there are more nodes than expected): 1) I checked the data and I noticed that some cities have the same name (i.e. `nome_ori`) but different codes and coordinates. Is that expected? See [here](https://gist.github.com/agila5/b96eb874154c99958a6f44652340d4ea) for an example.

Comment: Yes that's fine, those are 2 different cities with the same name (one of the many joys of dealing with data from a country as big as Brazil!). It is best to use the codes (`cod_ori`/`cod_dest`) to distinguish between cities, if there are places with the same code but different coordinates, that would be a problem. I hadn't seen that happen but I may have missed it!

Comment: Just realised, I didn't mention that there are duplicates of the connections within the shapefile I sent. I have been removing them using the following:

`'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))`

`regic_link <- st_read("REGIC2018_Ligacoes_entre_Cidades.shp") %>%`
  `mutate(check_orig = paste0(cod_ori, cod_dest),`
              `check_dest = paste0(cod_dest, cod_ori)) %>%`
               `# Remove duplicated links`
  `filter(check_orig %!in% regic_link$check_dest)`

Answer (score 2):

I will present a solution using a simplified example with only 5 `LINESTRING(s)`. If the following code corresponds to the desired solution, it should be easy to translate it to real-world cases.

First, define some functions and load relevant packages:

```r
'%!in%' <- function(x,y) !('%in%'(x,y))
Sys.setenv(`_R_S3_METHOD_REGISTRATION_NOTE_OVERWRITES_` = "false")
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(sf)
  library(lwgeom)
  library(tidygraph)
  library(sfnetworks)
})
```

Load data and select only the relevant columns + only five rows

```r
regic_link <- st_read(
  dsn = "city_link/REGIC2018_Ligacoes_entre_Cidades.shp",
  query = "SELECT cod_ori, cod_dest FROM REGIC2018_Ligacoes_entre_Cidades LIMIT 5"
)
#> Reading query `SELECT cod_ori, cod_dest FROM REGIC2018_Ligacoes_entre_Cidades LIMIT 5' from data source `C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\city_link\REGIC2018_Ligacoes_entre_Cidades.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -63.0338 ymin: -13.4945 xmax: -60.1348 ymax: -9.912
#> Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
```

Filter out duplicated connections

```r
regic_link <- regic_link %>%
  filter(paste0(cod_ori, cod_dest) %!in% paste0(cod_dest, cod_ori))
```

Build the sfnetwork object

```r
regic_sfn <- as_sfnetwork(regic_link, directed = FALSE)
```

Extract the nodes (i.e. the unique boundary points for those lines)

```r
regic_nodes <- st_as_sf(regic_sfn, "nodes")
```

Each node should correspond to a boundary point of the LINESTRINGS defined in
the object `regic_link`. As you noticed, we cannot simply use the from/to
columns since they don’t preserve the order of origin and destination. Hence,
we have to manually match the nodes with the starting points and the end
points (assuming that every time they have the same coordinates, then they
also have the same ID). Moreover, each node may correspond to several
(identical) boundary points, but we just need to take the first match (i.e.
the `[1]` notation below):

```r
start <- lapply(
  X = st_equals(regic_nodes, st_startpoint(regic_link)),
  FUN = function(x) regic_link$cod_ori[x[1]]
)
```

Check the output:

```r
start
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "1100015"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "1100023"
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] "1100031"
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] NA
```

This means that the first node corresponds to ID `1100015`, the seventh node
corresponds to ID `1100031` and so on. On the other hand, the other nodes do
not correspond to any starting point.
Repeat for the endpoints:

```r
end <- lapply(
  X = st_equals(regic_nodes, st_endpoint(regic_link)),
  FUN = function(i) regic_link$cod_dest[i[1]]
)
```

Check the output, which should be opposite wrt to `start` and with the same
interpretations:

```r
end
#> [[1]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "1100049"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "1100189"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "1100296"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] "1100114"
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] "1100304"
```

Combine the two objects. `dplyr::coalescence` is used to take the non-NA ID(s)

```r
idxs <- mapply(dplyr::coalesce, start, end)
```

Add the new ids to the nodes table:

```r
regic_sfn <- regic_sfn %N>%
  mutate(name = idxs)
```

Estimate the adjacency matrix among the cities

```r
regic_adj <- igraph::as_adjacency_matrix(regic_sfn, names = TRUE)
regic_adj
#> 8 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>         1100015 1100049 1100189 1100296 1100023 1100114 1100031 1100304
#> 1100015       .       1       1       1       .       .       .       .
#> 1100049       1       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
#> 1100189       1       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
#> 1100296       1       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
#> 1100023       .       .       .       .       .       1       .       .
#> 1100114       .       .       .       .       1       .       .       .
#> 1100031       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       1
#> 1100304       .       .       .       .       .       .       1       .
```

If we check the first row, we notice that the city is matched with the right
columns:

```r
regic_link %>% filter(cod_ori == 1100023)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -63.0338 ymin: -10.4323 xmax: -62.4721 ymax: -9.912
#> Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
#>   cod_ori cod_dest                       geometry
#> 1 1100023  1100114 LINESTRING (-63.0338 -9.912...
```

On the other hand

```r
regic_link %>% filter(cod_ori == 1100049)
#> Simple feature collection with 0 features and 2 fields
#> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
#> [1] cod_ori  cod_dest geometry
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

since that corresponds to one of the `cod_dest`.

```r
regic_link %>% filter(cod_dest == 1100049)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -62.0041 ymin: -11.9342 xmax: -61.4512 ymax: -11.4356
#> Geodetic CRS:  SIRGAS 2000
#>   cod_ori cod_dest                       geometry
#> 1 1100015  1100049 LINESTRING (-62.0041 -11.93...
```

Finally, we can convert the adj matrix to `inla.graph` object (but I think
that’s not strictly required by INLA functions):

```r
INLA::inla.read.graph(regic_adj)
#> $n
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> $nnbs
#> [1] 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> 
#> $nbs
#> $nbs[[1]]
#> [1] 2 3 4
#> 
#> $nbs[[2]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $nbs[[3]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $nbs[[4]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $nbs[[5]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $nbs[[6]]
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $nbs[[7]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> $nbs[[8]]
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> 
#> $graph.file
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $cc
#> $cc$id
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
#> 
#> $cc$n
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $cc$nodes
#> $cc$nodes[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> $cc$nodes[[2]]
#> [1] 5 6
#> 
#> $cc$nodes[[3]]
#> [1] 7 8
#> 
#> 
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "inla.graph"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Hope that helps. You can check the complete example removing `LIMIT 5` from the query argument in `st_read`. There might be some simpler approaches, but I cannot think of any right now.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed! 

One last little question...I have figured out that the extra nodes were created as their coordinates were very slightly different to other lines for the same city (all have a difference of 7.105427e-15). This means that the matrix has multiple rows/columns for the same cities. Is there a quick fix to set a boundary within which the nodes are considered equal? For example, if the difference in coordinates is <1e-10 they are considered the same node.

Comment: Check here: https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/preprocess_and_clean.html#common-pre-processing-tasks-1